# How would I implement pagination through php get requests

Tags: javascript, php

I have some code that supports pagination, but I can't make my buttons work. Can anyone help?

```
function setData() {
var flexContainer = document.getElementById("flex");
flexContainer.innerHTML = "<?php 
  foreach ($articlesarray as $seperated) {
    $contentsContent = file_get_contents("../" . "$seperated[contentsname]");
    echo "<div class='card'><img src='$seperated[img]'' alt='uh oh photo not found' style='width:100%''><div class='container'><h4><b>$seperated[title]</b></h4><p>$contentsContent</p></div></div>";
  }
 ?>";
document.getElementById("back").disabled = "<?php 
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/list/index.php?page=1") {
    echo "true";
  } else {
    echo "false";
  }
?>";
document.getElementById("back").style = "<?php 
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/list/index.php?page=1") {
    echo "display: none;";
  } else {
    echo "display: inline-block;";
  }
?>";
```

}

and the php is:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "You can't have my server password";
$dbname = "myDB";

$badurl = "/list/index.php";
$newURL = "/list/index.php?page=1";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']==$badurl) {
  print "uh oh spaghettios";
  header('Location: ' . $newURL);
  die();
}

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$offsetAmount = $_GET["page"] * 9 - 9;

$sql = "SELECT id, title, contentsname, img FROM articles LIMIT 9 OFFSET $offsetAmount";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$articlesarray = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $articlesarray[] = $row;
}

//echo "<br><br><br> If you are reading this, you have found the debug screen. This website is under maintanence.";

mysqli_close($conn);
```

I can't work out how to add pagination using this system. Can anyone help? I have tried shifting the url but that only returned a 0 for some reason.

Comment: "*I can't make my buttons work*" - what does that mean?  What does your rendered JS look like?

Comment: There is html to pull ot together. Php used a get request to know  what data to get from the table this is attached to the url as localhost/list?page=1 I would like the pagination to detect the page that you are on and act accordingly

Comment: The code is 1302 characters to long so have a look at this js fiddle instead. https://jsfiddle.net/sfhcvLr1/1/

Comment: Look at cursor pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a GET request so in PHP I can just use
`$_GET["page"]` and then add or subtract 1 accordingly.